# Having trouble getting minimum convex polygons using adehabitatHR-Error in is.character(i) : 'i' is missing

Tags: r

I'm trying to create minimum convex polygons using location data from 17 animals.  I create a list with two components, one component is the id number of each animal (I factored the id number) and the other component is the xy locations, class "SpatialPoints".  As far as I can tell, the data is formatted just as the adehabitatHR documentation details but when I go to calculate the MCP, I get an error messege:

```
    Error in is.character(i) : 'i' is missing
    In addition: Warning message:
    In rel[, 1] : j index ignored
```

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
    sdata@data = data.frame(sdata@data, v[match(rownames(sdata@data), rownames(v)),])
    sdata2 = sdata[(sdata$'usvsa' == '1'),(1:9)]
    sdata2$lynx<-as.factor(sdata2$lynx) #"lynx" is the name of the id# column
    sdata2=sdata2[-(1:8)]
    sdata2<-as.data.frame(sdata2)

    location=sdata2[-(3)]
    location<-SpatialPoints(location)
    id=sdata2[-(1:2)]
    lynxdata<- list(name= id, relocs=location)

   rel<- lynxdata$relocs
   cp <- mcp(rel[,1], percent=95)
```

Here's a summary of the lynxdata list:

```
    > summary(lynxdata)
          Length Class         Mode
   name       1  data.frame    list
   relocs 20623  SpatialPoints S4  

   > class (rel)
   [1] "SpatialPoints"
   attr(,"package")
   [1] "sp"
```

Any ideas as to what might be wrong with the organization of my data would be very appreciated!  Thanks!

Here what happens when I convert it into a data frame

```
     lynxdata2<-as.data.frame(lynxdata)
    > head(lynxdata2)
       lynx relocs.x relocs.y
     1  306 605738.8  1644068
     2  306 605504.2  1644478
     3  306 605503.0  1644456
     4  306 605352.8  1647556
     5  306 605437.8  1648239
     6  306 605353.8  1648314
     > cp <- mcp(lynxdata2[,1], percent=95)
     Error in mcp(lynxdata2[, 1], percent = 95) : 
     xy should be of class SpatialPoints
```

Comment: what does `class(rel)` return? Seems like it doesn't like the way you are indexing that variable.

Comment: Hi, class(rel)  tells me that rel is a  classified as "SpatialPoints".  I've added that bit of code to the above question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to extract the `x` values from `rel`? For some odd reason the SpatialPoints class only allows subsetting by row, not column. That's why are are getting that particular error. One method to extract the data would be to convert it to a data.frame and then extract the column. So you can replace your last line with

```
cp <- mcp(as.data.frame(rel)[,1], percent=95)
```

Comment: My mistake, I want to extract both x and y, column one should be the animal ID number.  So, I've fixed my data set so that it is no longer a list containing the factored id# and the SatialPoints xy locations.  Now it's a data frame so that the first column is the id#, the second is x, and the third is Y.  But, when I try the mcp function, I get a new error saying the xy must be of class SpatialPoints.  I've edited the above code to illustrate.

Comment: @user3088823 Well, i have no idea what the `mcp` function is supposed to do, but from your error message it sure sounds like it wants a class of `SpatialPoints` and not a data.frame. What about just `cp <- mcp(rel, percent=95)`. The problem is i'm not entire sure what your intention was with the `[,1]` in the first place.

Comment: Hi,  So the mcp function is supposed to take this list of locations, separate them by animal id (column 1), and then draw a minimum convex polygon around the locations of each animal.  It's a way of estimating a home range boundary for each animal.

Comment: I tried using 'cp<-mcp(rel, percent=95)' but get the error : 'XY must be of class SpatialPoints' even though they are!!  Thanks for your help, wish I knew more about this so I could give you better info.

Comment: @user3088823 If `class(rel)=="SpatialPoints"` and it says it's not, something must be wrong. Sorry. I've exhausted my ideas on what might be wrong for now.